# Solve for $\sqrt{x}+\sqrt[4]{y}=\sqrt{p}$ with $x$, $y$ are positive integers and $p$ is a prime number

Tags: elementary-number-theory

For that given problem, I have constructed a solution to it:

> Squaring both sides, we get $x+\sqrt{y}+2\sqrt[4]{x^2y}=p$. Suppose $\sqrt{y}$ and $\sqrt[4]{x^2y}$ are integers, we can let $y=y'^2$, $y'$ being a positive integer. Subbing to the equation, we get $x+y'+2\sqrt{xy'}=p$, so $(\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{y'})^2=p$. We can see that $\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{y'}$ is a positive integer, and $x$ and $y'$ are positive, so $\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{y'}>1$, so $(\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{y'})^2$ has at least 3 positive divisors, contradiction.

The only problem here is that I can't show that $\sqrt{y}$ and $\sqrt[4]{x^2y}$ are integers, because $\sqrt[4]{x^2y}=\sqrt{x\sqrt{y}}$, and I cannot guarantee that $x\sqrt{y}$ is an integer, so I can't show that they are both integers.

I would really appreciate it if I can get a hint on this problem, thank you a lot in advance.

Comment: Note that $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{x},\sqrt{p})/\mathbb{Q}$ is Galois with Galois group either $C_2$ or $V_4$. Because $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[4]{y})/\mathbb{Q}$ can't have Galois group $V_4$, it must be of degree $1$ or $2$ and $\sqrt{y}$ must be an integer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See that $\sqrt[4]y = (\sqrt p - \sqrt x)$ so
$$ y = (\sqrt p -\sqrt x)^4 = p^{2} - 4 \,  p \sqrt{px} + 6 \, p x - 4x \, \sqrt{px}  + x^{2} =p^2 +6px - \sqrt{px}(4x+4p) +x^2 $$ So you can easily see that $\sqrt{xp}$ is an integer.

Now $\sqrt y = (\sqrt p -\sqrt x)^2 = p + x - 2\sqrt{px}$ so $\sqrt y$ is an integer.

Also $\sqrt{x}\sqrt[4]y = x - \sqrt{px}$ which is an integer.

Comment: Problem: $\sqrt{xp} \in \mathbb Z^+ \Rightarrow x=a^2p \Rightarrow \sqrt x =a\sqrt p$. Substituting in the original equation we obtain $a\sqrt p +\sqrt [4] y =\sqrt p$  which implies $\sqrt [4] y < 0$. This means we must either (1) reject the usual practice of reporting roots as positive numbers, or (2) precede one of the left hand terms with a minus sign. When we do as much, we can find families of solutions by choosing arbitrary $p$ and arbitrary $a$, set $x=a^2p$ and $y=(a-1)^4p^2$, viz $a\sqrt p -(a-1)\sqrt p = \sqrt p$

Comment: @KeithBackman Indeed $\sqrt{xp}$ is an integer is not true by your method but OP wants to show that $\sqrt y$ and $\sqrt[4]{x^2 y}$ are integers to get a contradiction.

Answer (score 0):

There are not solution. In fact we have
$$y=(\sqrt p-\sqrt x)^4=p^2+6px+x^2-4(p+x)\sqrt{px}$$ One has three possible ways:

►If $x=p$ then $y=8p^2-8p^2=0$

►If $p+x=0$ then $y=2p^2-6p^2\lt0$

►If $x=pz^2$ then $y=p^2(z-1)^4$ which implies the given equation becomes
$(z+z-1)\sqrt p=\sqrt p\Rightarrow z=1\Rightarrow x=p$ which is the first possibility.